# Magento 2.1 adding new component type problem

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I added a new form element type called `Company\Module\Data\Form\Element\PdfButton`, when it is `version EE 2.0.7` and used this element in a custom tab(added by overriding `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tabs`) of product edit admin page.

After upgrading to Magento EE 2.1, the custom tab vanished. 
To make it appear, I added a modifier to make a new tab in product page. I successfully added a new tab by copying the modifier in vendor file and inject it to my module.

But, when I want to use my custom element.
So, in the children field of the meta array, I added following code:

```
$children[$website['id']] = [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Number::NAME,
                            'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Form\Element\Wysiwyg2::NAME,
                            'description' => __($website['name']),
                            'tooltip' => $tooltip,
                            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                            'dataScope' => 'website_ids.' . $website['id'],
                            'label' => "Pdf Upload",
                            'valueMap' => [
                                'true' => (string)$website['id'],
                                'false' => '0',
                            ],
                            'value' => $isChecked ? (string)$website['id'] : '0',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
```

after this, I copied the `Form\Element\Wysiwyg` and paste it as `Form\Element\Wysiwyg2`.
In the **Wysiwyg2** Class:

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Editor;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Wysiwyg\ConfigInterface;

/**
 * Class Input
 */
class Wysiwyg2 extends AbstractElement
{
    const NAME = 'wysiwyg2';

    /**
     * @var Form
     */
    protected $form;

    /**
     * @var Editor
     */
    protected $editor;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param ConfigInterface $wysiwygConfig
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     * @param array $config
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        ConfigInterface $wysiwygConfig,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        array $config = []
    ) {
        $wysiwygConfigData = isset($config['wysiwygConfigData']) ? $config['wysiwygConfigData'] : [];
        $this->form = $formFactory->create();
        $this->editor = $this->form->addField(
            $context->getNamespace() . '_' . $data['name'],
            'Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Editor',
            [
                'force_load' => true,
                'rows' => 20,
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'config' => $wysiwygConfig->getConfig($wysiwygConfigData),
                'wysiwyg' => isset($config['wysiwyg']) ? $config['wysiwyg'] : null,
            ]
        );
        $data['config']['content'] = $this->editor->getElementHtml();

        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get component name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getComponentName()
    {
        return static::NAME;
    }}
```

But there is an error and I don't know where I should add the name to that.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The requested component ("wysiwyg2") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The requested component ("wysiwyg2") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.
#0 /var/www/vhosts/plchk/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(207): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Provider\Component\Definition->getComponentData('wysiwyg2')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/plchk/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(187): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->createRawComponentData('wysiwyg2')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/plchk/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Field.php(82): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create(1, 'wysiwyg2', Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/plchk/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(148): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/plchk/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field))
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as my understanding, you are trying to add the whole new Ui component type which call `wysiwyg2`.

But unfortunately, there is a known issue about adding new Ui Component type (yes, just another one). You can check the original issue [overhere](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5647).

Let take a look deeper into how Magento 2 dealing with the Ui components in product form.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php

```
/**
 * Add wysiwyg properties
 *
 * @param ProductAttributeInterface $attribute
 * @param array $meta
 * @return array
 */
private function customizeWysiwyg(ProductAttributeInterface $attribute, array $meta)
{
    if (!$attribute->getIsWysiwygEnabled()) {
        return $meta;
    }

    $meta['arguments']['data']['config']['formElement'] = WysiwygElement::NAME;
    $meta['arguments']['data']['config']['wysiwyg'] = true;
    $meta['arguments']['data']['config']['wysiwygConfigData'] = [
        'add_variables' => false,
        'add_widgets' => false,
        'add_directives' => true,
        'use_container' => true,
        'container_class' => 'hor-scroll',
    ];

    return $meta;
}
```

And inside `public function setupAttributeMeta(ProductAttributeInterface $attribute, $groupCode, $sortOrder)`

Line 633 (may be different for each version)

```
        case 'textarea':
            $meta = $this->customizeWysiwyg($attribute, $meta);
            break;
```

As you can see, `customizeWysiwyg()` hard-coded `formElement` to `wysiwyg`.

If you want to `wysiwyg2` working, you need write a plugin for `setupAttributeMeta()` to add something like `$meta = $this->customizeWysiwyg2($attribute, $meta);`

But I do not encourage this, you can just create a preference for `\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Wysiwyg`, then inside the constructor you can do something like

```
/**
 * Wysiwyg constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory                          $formFactory
 * @param \Magento\Ui\Component\Wysiwyg\ConfigInterface                $wysiwygConfig
 * @param array                                                        $components
 * @param array                                                        $data
 * @param array                                                        $config
 */
public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    FormFactory $formFactory,
    ConfigInterface $wysiwygConfig,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = [],
    array $config = []
) {
    // Override the component for the WYSIWYG
    // This is not done using definition.xml due to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5647
    $data['config']['component'] = 'Stackoverflow_Toan/js/form/element/wysiwyg';

    // Override the templates to include our KnockoutJS code
    $data['config']['template'] = 'Stackoverflow_Toan/wysiwyg';
    $data['config']['elementTmpl'] = 'Stackoverflow_Toan/wysiwyg';

    parent::__construct($context, $formFactory, $wysiwygConfig, $components, $data, $config);
}
```

By this way, you can have your own *jsComponent, knockout templates*..etc and ready to customise to whatever you want.

Hope this helps :)